# How to find bifurcation value from a potential

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, chaos-theory, bifurcation

[image]

Just needed some guidance to see if my approach is correct.
The following is how I proceeded to do this problem. What seems to be confusing me is that it is in the potential form and not $\dot{x} = ...$. From the equation I can tell that this is a saddle node bifurcation.

$$x' = r- x^2$$

Since we know that $x' = -\frac{dV}{dx}$, we can integrate the system to solve for the potential.
$$ V = \frac{x^3}{3} -rx + C$$
We can let $C= 0$.
Therefore:
$$ V = \frac{x^3}{3} - rx$$

The following graphs are the graphs for values of $r > 0 , r < 0$ and $r = 0$.
[image]

The question asks to include bifurcation values (r critical), how would I go about finding those? From my understanding I know the bifurcation occurs when the two curves $x^3/3$ and $-rx$ are tangent to each other. So I can take the derivative of both of them then solve for x then plug that into the equation for V to solve for r. Is this correct?

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is correct? It doesn't make sense to speak about equilibria in the current statement of the problem. Maybe you can upload a photo of problem formulation?

Comment: @Evgeny I think I misunderstood the problem. I will delete this post and post another with the actual problem.

Comment: Well, do you actually need to delete it completely? You can just edit it, the problem technically will stay the same, right?

Comment: @Evgeny I've edited the question

Comment: Let me just explain in short when there is a bifurcation in equation $\dot{x} = f(x, \alpha)$. A bifurcation happens at $\alpha = \alpha_0$ if there is some equilibrium $p$ (i.e. $f(p) = 0$) and $f'(p) = 0$. Geometrically this means that $f(x)$ has a non-simple zero at point $p$ — the graph $y = f(x)$ is tangent to $Ox$ axis. Even in case of a system defined by a potential everything regarding equilibria and bifurcations comes down to analyzing the right hand side of equation.